# Синхронный клиент для асинхронного сервера

Tags: linux, c, асинхронность, epoll

Мне необходимо написать сервер, который обрабатывает множество соединений одновременно. Для этого думаю использовать механизмы на основе системного вызова `epoll`.

Есть загвоздка. Клиентская часть системы синхронная. В ней на один реквест/респонс используется один поток. Нормально ли это и какие могут возникнуть проблемы?

Comment: Нормально, архитектура клиента и архитектура сервера не влияют друг на друга вообще никак

Comment: По Вашему вопросу согласен с  andreymal, но хотел бы сказать, что написание сервера через *epoll* - не самая хорошая идея. Если это не учебное приложение, а планируется использование в реальной жизни, то лучше посмотрите вот как это делается в настоящих серверах: "Пример разработки простого многопоточного сетевого сервера с поддержкой пользовательских сессий на языке C в ОС GNU/Linux" - https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-server1/

Там серия из 7 статаей.

Comment: @Sergey, не стоит вводить в заблуждение... `epoll` — это серьёзный интерфейс, используемый для серверов с высокой нагрузкой... Понятно, что на многопроцессорных системах нужно будет разделить на нити/процессы, заняв все ядра, но на большинстве видов нагрузки `epoll` будет быстрее, чем «классический» чисто-`fork`'ающийся демон...

Comment: libuv сделает ваш epoll проще

Comment: кстати, забыл добавить, из подводных камней на стороне клиента надо не забыть обработать отсутствие ответа сервера...

Answer (score 0):

Это нормально, проблем не возникнет если интерфейс пользователя в отдельном потоке.